# Google maps V3 JS no happen "center_changed" from UIWebView iOS6(iPhone)

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3, ios6-maps

I'm trying to display `GoogleMap(Google maps V3 JS)` in `UIWebView(ios6)`.
but,
When I moveing the map in webview,event no fire `center_changed`.
Move map has been completed, event fire.
Why?
...
Someone told me page:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html
Mac' Safri access - fire `center_changed` while the map is moving.
iOS6 Safri access - move map is complete, fire `center_changed`.

...
I want to know the Center-Cordinates of the map while moving.
Please tell me a good way.

```
`<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: iPhone Geolocation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var moveCenterLat;
var moveCenterLng;

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
    zoom:reqZoomLevel,
    disableDefaultUI:true,
    draggable:true,
    keyboardShortcuts:false,
    scrollwheel:false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){
    var mce = map.getCenter();
    moveCenterLat = mce.lat();
    moveCenterLng = mce.lng();
});

}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something that doesn't work on google maps on IOS devices. The center_changed is fired when the map is dragged but the center does not update until the drag is complete. So the answer is, 'no', you can not do this.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want the `drag` event, not `center_changed`. From the [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference):

> **drag**: this event is repeatedly fired while the user drags the map.

Something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(){
    var mce = map.getCenter();
    moveCenterLat = mce.lat();
    moveCenterLng = mce.lng();
});
```

**Edit:** It seems the map bounds are no longer updated while dragging, so although the drag event does fire while the map is being dragged, both `getCenter()` returns the coordinates of the map when the drag started. Thanks to @Zubair for pointing this out.

Comment: This is incorrect as while drag does fire when the map is moved, the lat and lng are not updated, and are actually the values at the start of the drag operation

Comment: @Zubair: this definitely used to work, but you're correct, it's no longer updating. See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/lazd/ReLf7/