# Google Maps API: forcing zoom in to a specific location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm quite new with the Google Maps API and I was wondering if there is a way to force the zoom in to a specific location, for example: the US.

What I'm looking for is a way to simulate the kind of zooming in effect of the mouse scrolling wheel, if the cursor is in the US, when you zoom in with the scrolling wheel, the center will start moving towards the cursor.

I tried using the 'zoom_changed' event and changing the center dynamically, but since it is not running in a desktop (device mode), the event is only triggered at the end ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750750/google-maps-drag-event-doesnt-capture-center-change-until-dragging-ends-in-chro)).

Here is my code:

```
var map;
var centerUS;
var currentCenter;
var currentZoom;

function initMap() {
    //define Map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 3,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    //limit the zoom
    map.setOptions({ minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 10 });

    //initialization of variables
    currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    currentCenter = map.getCenter();
    centerUS = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100);

    //add the listener for zooming in
    map.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
        zoomInTheUS();
    });
}

function zoomInTheUS() {

    //get new values
    var newZoom = map.getZoom();
    currentCenter = map.getCenter();

    //if the user is zooming in
    if (newZoom > currentZoom) {

        //difference between the current center and the center of the US
        var changeLat = centerUS.lat() - currentCenter.lat();
        var changeLng = centerUS.lng() - currentCenter.lng();

        //approach the center of the US by a factor of 10% of the distance
        var newLat = currentCenter.lat() + changeLat * 0.1;
        var newLng = currentCenter.lng() + changeLng * 0.1;

        //define new center and pan to it
        var newCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng);
        map.panTo(newCenter);
    }

    //actualize the value of currentZoom
    currentZoom = newZoom;
}
```

I tried to do it during the 'drag' event because it is triggered repeatedly, but it doesn't work. I think it may be because the event is triggered very quickly and the newZoom and currentZoom variable almost always have the same value. Or maybe, on device mode, the zoom variable from the Google Maps API is refreshed at the end of an event. I am only assuming, I do not know.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I thought of disabling the panning when 2 fingers are detected or maybe changing from device mode to non-device mode, but I haven't found anything about it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could save yourself the trouble and only serve tiles of the US, that way the user couldn't look outside of the US even if they wanted to.

Comment: please review my answer if it helped and if it didn't please post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to locate your own location first and then auto-zoom to that location. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930874/7707749

I made here an example how you can zoom into the location you wish to zoom in for:

```js
function getPlaces(query) {
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
   document.getElementById('attributions') //attributions-container
 );

 //send a query
 service.textSearch({query:query}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        
    addMapMarker(results[i], i);
   }
   
   map.fitBounds(mapPointsBounds);
  }
 });
}


function addMapMarker(markerInfo, i) {

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker;
 var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
 
 var marker;
 
 //this is where the marker is created with position and animation
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position:  markerInfo.geometry.location,
  map: map,
            markerInfo: markerInfo
 });
 
 allMarkers.push(marker); //keeping all markers in an array    
 mapPointsBounds.extend(markerInfo.geometry.location); //extend bounds to contain this marker
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
   infowindow.setContent('<div>This is marker:' + marker + '</div>');
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
 })(marker, i));
}
```

```css
#map {
 height: 100%;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://developers.google.com/places/documentation/images/powered-by-google-on-white.png"/>

<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" runat="server" onchange="initMap(this.value)"/>  
  
<ul id="results"></ul>

<div id="attributions" style="background:#f1f1f1"> You'll see here the attributions when there are any </div>
  
<div id="map"></div>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places" async defer></script>
<script>
    var startLatLng, //change this to some value near to where the map will end up
 allMarkers = [], //keep a global copy of your markers
 mapPointsBounds = [], //map bounds of all markers
 map; //copy of the map

 //Google will call this when it's ready, it's a query string in the script tag above `&callback=initMap`:
    function initMap(query) {
        startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng([0, 0]);
 mapPointsBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: startLatLng,
  zoom: 13
 });
    
 getPlaces(query);
    }
</script>
```