# How to get lat-long values of all areas in a city

Tags: geocoding, latitude-longitude, google-geocoding-api

I have tried to find a lot over the Internet but I am unable to get a perfect utility/API for my requirement.

I am interested in getting the latitude, longitude values of all areas in a city.

Currently i am using this google maps api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

But, when i enter a city name, it is giving only one lat-long pair for that city. Is there any way that if i give a city name, i can get all the areas and their corresponding latitude, longitude values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice documentation for this at: [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)

I used this to get the latitude / longitude for one of my own projects and I also have an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43277145/7707749) of this.

If you look at the example, you can just type a location and it will immediately get the lat / long of the location and zoom in, you can also do this for more locations at the same time. Remember there is a limit for the `maps api` so it can only process so many data at the same time. Hope this may help you out! :)